# During download of executable of chrome extension getting Failed-Network error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension. And as soon as user adds extension to chrome, new html page is opened and executable file downloaded to user machine. All needed files including exe takes part during packing process. But when I try to add extension, there is a problem with downloading exe: "Failed-Network error". Chrome acts my exe as a malicious software. How can I make my exe trustful?

Comment: I warned you ;)

Comment: As a user I certainly wouldn't want extensions to be able to download and automatically run malware exe.

Comment: This is part of Google's security measures as I found a [blog post with regard to Chrome blocking exe files](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Chrome-to-block-downloads-of-hazardous-exe-files-1222643.html).

Comment: Exe will not run automatically. Will be downloaded automatically and user will start to run it.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of Google's security measures as I found a [blog post with regard to Chrome blocking exe files](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Chrome-to-block-downloads-of-hazardous-exe-files-1222643.html).